# Removing Google contacts from iPod contacts

Tags: sync, ipod-touch

Like [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/40421/accidentally-synced-all-google-contacts-to-iphone), I sync'd contacts with my Google list, and it's now basically junk.

Is there a way to "unsync" it, so that all the Google contacts are deleted?

I do have two lists in my Google contacts - the original ones from my iPod, and a 2nd with all the random emails my account has accumulated.  Can I sync just the first list somehow?

Answer (score 2):

The iPod Touch/iPhone syncs to the **My Contacts** list in Google Contacts. Just make sure this list contains only the contacts you want on your iPod, and the extra ones will be removed from your iPod when you sync. If you still want access to the random accumulated email addresses in Google Contacts, they will appear in the **All Contacts** list.